# Emacs: what is over-riding my global-set-key assignment?

Tags: emacs

I have a file `init-keybindings.el` that I load via `.emacs`, right at the end of a chain of init files. Nothing is executed via `.emacs` after this. The final few lines of this keybindings file are given below. Since yesterday the `f11` and `f12` key assignments have stopped working.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") 'my-copy-region)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f11>") 'kill-this-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f1>") 'save-buffer)
```

For example, if I hit `f12` the cursor moves up. Hitting `C-h k f12` gives "C-p runs the command previous-line". If I do `M-x my-copy-region` the function works as I would expect, so the function itself seems to be valid and was working fine 24 hours ago.

Likewise, hitting `f11` doesn't do what is expected: it brings up an isearch minibuffer rather than killing the current buffer. Hitting `C-h k f11` yields "C-s runs the command isearch-forward". That fits with what I'm seeing, but it should be doing something different.

So something appears to be interfering with the `global-set-key` assignments. I'm running v24.3.1 under Windows 7 and have searched for other (non-Emacs) programs that might be interfering with this but with no success. I've also checked my input language, which seems unchanged.

Have I inadvertently flipped a switch somewhere in Emacs?

[image: mode line]

Comment: Try to evaluate in `*scratch*` buffer  `emacs-lisp-mode-hook` and see if there's something there you don't expect to be. Also do the same for all minor modes you are using. It will be there somewhere.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. Turns out that on my Microsoft 4000 keyboard there is an "F Lock" key that [toggles the function keys](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894513) to do something different. I was looking for a software issue but it was a hardware problem instead. The problem is now resolved. Should I leave this question here?

Comment: Why not? This looks may spark a light bulb for someone else too.

Comment: However, you might want to post your solution as an answer and accept it, so that this question no longer shows up as unresolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a Microsoft 4000 Natural Ergonomic Keyboard. Although I had never noticed it until today, this keyboard has an "F Lock" key to the right of the `F12` key that [toggles the function keys](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894513) to do something different (the exact function can be set using the keyboard's utility software). With this key toggled, my function keys in Emacs were giving the strange results described in the original question above. So if you have a keyboard with many extra keys, such as this one or one of the Logitech keyboards, beware of the key that shifts the function keys.